# Unable to execute heat_cpu on ARM, unable to find the source code

Tags: linux, performance, power-management, linaro

I want to test the cpu pm operation using this tool. I got the binaries which are running on X86:

```
git://github.com/JackyBai/pm-test/
```

But i did not find the source code of that. As i want to run on ARM64, can anybody help me to share the link. The below link is not working,

```
git://git.linaro.org/people/amitdanielk/thermal-test.git master
```

Error message:

```
 access denied or repository not exported: /people/amitdanielk/thermal-test.git
```

Comment: Solved..https://wiki.linaro.org/WorkingGroups/PowerManagement/Resources/TestSuite/PmQaSpecification